# creating different color spans using REST api

Tags: google-cloud-trace

I've seen some trace screenshots where different spans have different colors (https://rakyll.org/grpc-trace/).

I've tried tracing my code using the v2 rest api, and all of the resulting spans are in uniform shades of blue.

How are these colors determined? I don't see an explicit color attribute in v2 rest api. Is color inferred from some other attribute? 
Is it an old feature that was abandoned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to set colors; we only have spans in blue color. The colors in the [article](https://rakyll.org/grpc-trace/) are old screenshots from a previous version of the UI. We used to have them in different colors based on whether they were the root span.

We have considered different coloring options at various times, but there are no actual plans around this. If you are still interested in this feature, you can create a feature request using the following [Issue Trackers](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187216&template=0).